# Numpy - referencing values in other array for multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a k nearest neighbor classifier in Numpy and faiss (Facebook kNN library). For point classification, I receive:

```
[[ 9240  4189  8702]
 [ 2639  1052 13565]
 [10464 14220 13980]
 ...
 [12014 12063  1331]
 [ 6719  5832  8827]
 [ 1793  5455 12328]]
```

Each row is an index of the `y` vector. I need to reference the values for this matrix in the `y` vector, so e. g. I will swap `9240` in the matrix for `y[9240]` value, for example 1 (positive class).

Can I do that without Python loop, i. e. can this be done with Numpy only?

Comment: Is `y` a 1d vector?

Comment: It sounds like you just want `y[your_array]`

Comment: @alani Yeah, that's it! For some reason I thought it would not work for multicolumn X... please post an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @qalis Okay, have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index a 1-d array with an array of indices. The result is the same shape as the array of indices. For example:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 2]])

>>> y
array([ 1000.,  1020.,  1040.,  1060.])

>>> y[a]
array([[ 1020.,  1040.,  1040.],
       [ 1060.,  1060.,  1040.]])
```